# React Native Spash Screen with resize mode 'contain' in app.json

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im using a splash image with gradient in app.json in an Expo project. Its resize mode is set to contain. Now it takes space both from top and bottom. While adding any background color it does not match with the image as image is made through gradient.
Any solution would be highly appreciated.

For some reason cannot use any other resize mode other than contain.

```
"splash": {
  "image": "./src/assets/images/splash_screen.png",
  "resizeMode": "contain",
  "backgroundColor": "#2962FF"
},
```

Comment: It is very unclear, what you are asking for. Please include some details as code or screenshots and a clear description of what you want to achieve.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply, I have added the code if you help me out

Comment: Thank you! Could you also add a screenshot of how it is currently looking?

Comment: What happens when you use `resizeMode: "cover"` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
"resizeMode": "cover"
```